# Attempting to use index type '-1' where index types are not allowed (1 or -1 only)

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using:

```
$db->collection->find()->sort(array('username' => '-1'));
```

And I keep getting the error:

> MongoCursorException: localhost:27017: Attempting to use index type
>   '-1' where index types are not allowed (1 or -1 only).

I am using MongoDB 2.4.1 with PHP driver 1.3.x.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have called sort like so:

```
sort(array('username' => '-1'));
```

Which is a problem. In MongoDB 2.4.1 there is a slight quirk (bug?) which means that it will not accept strings any more for sort ordering.

Since this is not in the driver but instead in the server (MongoDB itself) simply changing driver version will not fix this.

This could have existed earlier than MongoDB 2.4.1 however, I merely tested this on MongoDB 2.0.0 and 2.1.x whereby I did not observe this behaviour on the same PHP driver version (1.2.x and 1.3.x).

To fix this you must specify a signed numerical figure like so:

```
sort(array('username' => -1));
```

That will work.

#### Edit

After posting in the mongodb-user Google group, I found out this was not a bug, however, it is still something to be aware of.

Comment: You will see the same effects with any MongoDB driver, not only PHP. We are using JavaScript (via mongoose) and have this.  The issue is explained [here] (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-index-types/)  but it was not immediately clear that just setting the sort uses some kind of temporary or virtual index.